# Error: cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

I have been struggling with the following error. I am performing MCMC simulation with Rcpp Armadillo functions. The code could retrieve true parameters in the past. The simulation works alright for few number of iterations and then the error appears all of a sudden. Or, R session will be terminated with a fatal error. I monitored the numbers stored and they are realistic. The code works fine some times (as a miracle), but now it is occurring every time. I would like to get some insight into the reasons behind this error. I can post the code for the function if it is relevant for resolving the issue.

```
Error in as.vector(post_L(r, y)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.vector': Error in as.vector(post_L(r,y)) : 
cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'double'

#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;
```

Here is the call to the function:

```
 L <- as.vector(post_L(r,y))
```

Here is the function:

```
 vec post_L(double r, vec y) {

  RNGScope scope;
  Environment base("package:base");
  Function sample = base["sample"];

  int n = y.size(); 
 double den_sum;
  mat F = Fmatrix(y);
  vec L,samp_temp, Prob_L;     
  L.zeros(n);

  for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
  {
      if (y(i)==0) {
      L(i) = 0;
      }
      else {      
     Prob_L.zeros(y(i));
     den_sum = 0; 
    for(int k=0; k<y(i); ++k)
   {
    if(F((y(i)-1),k)==0) {
      den_sum= den_sum; 
    }
    if(F((y(i)-1),k)!=0) {
    den_sum += F((y(i)-1),k)*pow(r,k);
    }
  }
  for (int j=0; j<y(i); ++j)
  {
    if(F((y(i)-1),j)==0) {
      Prob_L(j) = 0;
    }
    if(F((y(i)-1),j)!=0) {
      Prob_L(j) = (F((y(i)-1),j)*pow(r,j))/den_sum;
    }        
  }                

  samp_temp.zeros(y(i));
  for(int z = 0; z<y(i); ++z)
  {
    samp_temp(z) =  (z+1);
  }

  L(i) = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(samp_temp, 1, F, Prob_L);

  }
 }

 return(L);  
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Post code or nobody will be able to help you as the mind-reading device is in the shop for maintenance.

Comment: @Dirk: Thank you for your response and I added the relevant code. Sorry for not posting it earlier.

Comment: This is fundamentally flawed. You probably do *not* want the R function sample as it, as an R function, will run at R speed. There is a contributed sample function in the RcppArmadillo package; and an article at the Rcpp Gallery about it.  I would study that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk. I tried the sample function. But, I have the following error. "reference to RcppArmadillo is ambiguous." I remember trying this in the past as well. Sorry for my ignorance (if any obvious fix is there). Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I fixed that mistake. Now I use Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(samp_temp, 1, F, Prob_L); Just a question on the sample function. It only takes Rcpp vectors right ? It does not take RcppArmadillo vectors. So, I need to convert it ? I found a similar thread for that help. It would be great if you can confirm this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help on the sample function idea. I fixed every thing. Things are running fine. Thanks.